# Assigning values in looped dictionary

Tags: python

I am struggling with this loop where I want to assign values to a nested dictionary. I have a list called **stp2** and a default dict that I created with **none** as values.
I am trying to take list elements one by one and assign to the dictionary.

```
stp2=['Anna', 'William', 'Mary', 'Ben', 'Richard','Calvin', 'Rock']
```

whereas my_dict is a default dict (nested) which looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {0: {'name': None, 'price': None,}, 1:{'name': None, 'price': None,}, 2: {'name': None, 'price': None,}, 3: {'name': None, 'price': None,}, 4: {'name': None, 'price': None,}, 5: {'name': None, 'price': None,}, 6: {'name': None, 'price': None,}})
```

I am using this loop to update values:

```
for z in enumerate(stp2):
 my_dict[z[0]]['name']=z[1]

print(my_dict)
```

My output should ideally look like this but I am getting "Rock" in every value repeated.

Ideal output:

```
{0: {'name': 'Anna', 'price': None,}, 1:{'name': 'William', 'price': None,}, 2: {'name': 'Mary', 'price': None,}, 3: {'name': 'Ben', 'price': None,}, 4: {'name': 'Richard', 'price': None,}, 5: {'name': 'Calvin', 'price': None,}, 6: {'name': 'Rock', 'price': None,}}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two lines

initializing empty dictionary

```
>>> dict={}
```

Updating dictionary using list comprehension

```
>>> for l1 in [{i:{'name':j,'price':None}} for i,j in enumerate(stp2)]:
    dict.update(l1)
```

Final dictionary

```
>>> dict
{0: {'price': None, 'name': 'Anna'}, 1: {'price': None, 'name': 'William'}, 2: {'price': None, 'name': 'Mary'}, 3: {'price': None, 'name': 'Ben'}, 4: {'price': None, 'name': 'Richard'}, 5: {'price': None, 'name': 'Calvin'}, 6: {'price': None, 'name': 'Rock'}}
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks a ton. Do you mind explaining why [z[0]] in my code (which resolves properly if I use print statement for every loop isn't taking right position/values? I was thinking that in first loop it should be my_dict[0]['name']='Anna'

Comment: Your code also works fine for me. Are you sure its not giving correct results?

Comment: Yes, the way I was doing is giving me Rock for every value in 'name. I am perplexed.

Comment: @anna This means your data structure is using the *same* dictionary for each entry in `my_dict`. Unfortunately you don't show how  `my_dict` was initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. you are not updating the key that's the reason you are getting the same value for all keys in dict.

```
stp2=['Anna', 'William', 'Mary', 'Ben', 'Richard','Calvin', 'Rock']
d = {
 0: {'name': None, 'price': None},
 1: {'name': None, 'price': None},
 2: {'name': None, 'price': None},
 3: {'name': None, 'price': None},
 4: {'name': None, 'price': None},
 5: {'name': None, 'price': None},
 6: {'name': None, 'price': None}}
for index, value in enumerate(stp2):                                                                                                      
   d[index]['name'] = value
print d
# output: 
{0: {'name': 'Anna', 'price': None},
 1: {'name': 'William', 'price': None},
 2: {'name': 'Mary', 'price': None},
 3: {'name': 'Ben', 'price': None},
 4: {'name': 'Richard', 'price': None},
 5: {'name': 'Calvin', 'price': None},
 6: {'name': 'Rock', 'price': None}}
```

Comment: `my_dict[z[0]]['name']=z[1]` this statement in anna code does the same thing as dictionary update method

Answer (score 0):

In your enumerate I believe `z` isn't pointing to the names the way you think it should.

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
tmp = {}
counter = 0
for person in stp2:
    tmp = {'name': person, 'price': None}
    my_dict[0] = tmp
    tmp = {}
    counter += 1

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: this yields: `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: sorry I forgot that it's not attribute, I modified code to handle same use case

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. `tmp` isn't really needed, and you have a `defaultdict` but never use it's features.  Also `list` doesn't make sense as a default value here.